# method compiling gives "missing return statement" error

Tags: java

What is wrong with this method?
This won't compile.
Gives an error like: rs might not be initialised
If I use "ResultSet rs" inside the try block then the error is: variable rs not found
If return statement is also inside try block, then error is: missing return statement.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Please help in fixing this error.
Thanks

```
public ResultSet mqe( String q ){
ResultSet rs;
try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String db= "SS.mdb";
String database= "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+ db.trim()+ ";DriverID=22}";
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection( database,"","" );
Statement s= conn.createStatement();
rs=s.executeQuery(q);
s.close();
conn.close();
}catch(Exception ee){ ee.printStackTrace(); }
return rs;
}//mqe
```

Comment: did u try initializing `ResultSet rs=null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a `ResultSet` for every possible execution path. As it stands, if the `try` block succeeds, nothing will be returned. You could add a `finally` block to your `try-catch` and put a `return null;` in there or `return rs;` which is null since you don't initialize it.

```
public ResultSet mqe( String q ){
ResultSet rs;

    try{
    ...
    }catch(Exception ee){
       ee.printStackTrace(); }
       return rs;
    }finally
    {
       return rs;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally the pattern for resource acquisition and release is:

```
Resource res = acquire();
try {
    use(res);
} finally {
    res.release();
}
```

Or in Java SE 7:

```
try (Resource res = acquire()) {
    use(res);
}
```

Something you can't do (by default) is return a resource from a method and expect it to be cleaned up by some sort of magic. You may want to look at the Execute Around idiom, although first a better understanding of the fundamentals may be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going, add this as the last line of the method:

```
return null;
```

At least then you can start debugging (which you'll probably need a lot of).

Comment: Hi, Thanks! adding a ResultSet rs=null and a finally block worked.